# Is scaring Muslims allowed even if we are just kidding?

Tags: sunnah, adab

I know that scaring Muslims is not allowed in Islam. But if I scare my friend just for fun is that allowed or not?

For example in the TV programs when they scare people, they meant to just 
kidd with them.

Comment: Why -1??, Is there something i have missed??

Comment: I didn't DV you, If you just say 'scaring', you are a bit ambiguous. Try adding an example.

Comment: You could add something like 'playing a prank' instead of 'scaring'. I have asked for word suggestions at [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73728/is-there-a-single-word-for-scaring-a-person-for-sake-of-fun/73730#73730). Follow up the question and update your question after you get a more relevant word.

Comment: Possible dupe of: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/is-mocking-a-friend-in-a-friendly-way-forbidden

Comment: @ashes999 I'm taking about friends and not friends and my question is about scaring not any action :)

Comment: @TabrezAhmed i put an example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not allowed the prophet(Peace be upon him) inhibition for doing that

> The Companions of the Prophet () told us that they were travelling
>   with the Prophet (). A man of them slept, and one of them went to the
>   rope which he had with him. He took it, by which he was frightened.
>   The Prophet () said: It is not lawful for a Muslim that he frightens a
>   Muslim.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ سُلَيْمَانَ الأَنْبَارِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ
>   نُمَيْرٍ، عَنِ الأَعْمَشِ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ يَسَارٍ، عَنْ
>   عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ أَبِي لَيْلَى، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا أَصْحَابُ،
>   مُحَمَّدٍ صلى الله عليه وسلم أَنَّهُمْ كَانُوا يَسِيرُونَ مَعَ
>   النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَنَامَ رَجُلٌ مِنْهُمْ فَانْطَلَقَ
>   بَعْضُهُمْ إِلَى حَبْلٍ مَعَهُ فَأَخَذَهُ فَفَزِعَ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ
>   اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ لاَ يَحِلُّ لِمُسْلِمٍ أَنْ يُرَوِّعَ
>   مُسْلِمًا ‏"‏ ‏.‏

[Abu Dawud - Book 43 - Hadith no 232](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43#232)

> The Apostle of Allah () said: None of you should take the property of
>   his brother in amusement (i.e. jest), nor in earnest. The narrator
>   Sulayman said: Out of amusement and out of earnest. If anyone takes
>   the staff of his brother, he should return it. The transmitter Ibn
>   Bashshar did not say "Ibn Yazid, and he said: The Apostle of Allah ()
>   said.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ بَشَّارٍ، حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى، عَنِ ابْنِ
>   أَبِي ذِئْبٍ، ح وَحَدَّثَنَا سُلَيْمَانُ بْنُ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ
>   الدِّمَشْقِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا شُعَيْبُ بْنُ إِسْحَاقَ، عَنِ ابْنِ أَبِي
>   ذِئْبٍ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ السَّائِبِ بْنِ يَزِيدَ، عَنْ
>   أَبِيهِ، عَنْ جَدِّهِ، أَنَّهُ سَمِعَ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه
>   وسلم يَقُولُ ‏"‏ لاَ يَأْخُذَنَّ أَحَدُكُمْ مَتَاعَ أَخِيهِ لاَعِبًا
>   وَلاَ جَادًّا ‏"‏ ‏.‏ وَقَالَ سُلَيْمَانُ ‏"‏ لَعِبًا وَلاَ جِدًّا ‏"‏
>   ‏.‏ ‏"‏ وَمَنْ أَخَذَ عَصَا أَخِيهِ فَلْيَرُدَّهَا ‏"‏ ‏.‏ لَمْ يَقُلِ
>   ابْنُ بَشَّارٍ ابْنِ يَزِيدَ وَقَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله
>   عليه وسلم ‏.‏

[Abu Dawud - Book 43 - Hadith no 231](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43#231)

Answer (score 1):

> For example, in TV programs when they scare people, they are just kidding with them.

There are lots of horror movies on tv whete people are 'scared'. But of course they aren't 'scared'. They are merely acting.

In the example you gave, they aren't truly 'scaring' people, but joking with them. This has nothing to do with 'scaring' people in the proper sense of the word, but as you point out, it os a joke. To truly 'scare' people as a joke will be seen as as a bad joke in bad taste.